# Unable to connect to kafka in docker from Spring boot in host machine

Tags: spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka

I have already gone though [Robin Moffat's blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/), and several SO posts on the same subject, but still my configuration doesnt work.

My docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.1.2
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
#      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDEDOCKER://kafka:9092,HOSTMACHINE://kafka:29092 # doesnt work
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDEDOCKER://kafka:9092,HOSTMACHINE://0.0.0.0:29092 # also doesnt work 
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDEDOCKER://kafka:9092,HOSTMACHINE://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDEDOCKER:PLAINTEXT,HOSTMACHINE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDEDOCKER
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "false"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
```

And my bootstrap servers value in Springboot app:

```
kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:29092
```

I still get errors like:

```
Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:29092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

Can someone point out what I am missing?

Comment: Did you try this one too? It covers the specific scenario you're talking about: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Hey! while we are here, in your blog (one i linked).. there's a section "Here’s the Docker Compose snippet" .. but no actual snippet below! Maybe u missed it :). And.. it seems i needed to give the docker-ip for external connection in both adv.listeners as well as springboot! (we use docker-toolbox at work, and the usual localhost doesn't work).

Comment: Docker Toolbox has been deprecated for several years. Are you sure that is what you are using? Is your Spring app a container as well, or not? (Note: `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` is the property name you should be using)